# Using strings in defining rules

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

I am very new using Mathematica and I would like to define a rule of replacement which operates as below, keeping freedom for what concern the pre-factors that can appear in the equation:
$$e^{\pm ix} \to \delta(\pm x).$$

```
ruleInt = {Exp[I A___ x] -> DiracDelta[A x] }
```

but it works with the plus, not with the minus sign and it does not work with any other symbol, such as a number or a variable. I also tried to write my string A followed by one or two or underscores, but actually I am not able to control it as it is not clear the difference between those possibilities. The Wolfram manual was of any help.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: But $\delta (+x) = \delta (-x)$.

Comment: Yes David, it has to be meant symbolically. I had in mind cases such as:
$$ e^{i (\epsilon- \pm \epsilon^'}t}->\delta(\epsilon \pm \epsilon').$$

I intentionally omitted it to focus on the generic nature of the symbol I wanted to appear there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you used the term ***"my string A"*** in the question that is not quite the correct nomenclature. ***A*** is what is known as a **named pattern**.

At the moment, `ruleInt` does not need curly brackets (although there is also no harm).

```
ruleInt = Exp[I A___ x] -> DiracDelta[A x]
```

Let's try your rule on the following test cases.

```
{Exp[-4 I], Exp[I x], Exp[2 x I], Exp[-2 x I], Exp[a x I], 
  Exp[-a x I]} /. ruleInt
```

with the result

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works on the second and fifth elements of the list.

It is very helpful when making replacement rules to look at the `FullForm` of expressions. Indeed the full form is the syntax that is actually used when performing replacements.

```
FullForm[Exp[-4 I]]
```

Power[E, Complex[0,-4]]

```
FullForm[Exp[I x]]
```

Power[E, Times[Complex[0,1],x]

```
FullForm[Exp[2 x I]]
```

Power[E, Times[Complex[0,2],x]

```
FullForm[Exp[-2 x I]]
```

Power[E, Times[Complex[0,-2],x]

```
FullForm[Exp[a x I]]
```

Power[E, Times[Complex[0,1],a,x]

```
FullForm[Exp[-a x I]]
```

Power[E, Times[Complex[0,-1],a,x]

Observe that `Times` only occurs when a symbol is present. This suggest modify `ruleInt` to take into account two cases (now we will use the curly brackets).

```
ruleInt2={Power[E,Complex[0,x_?NumberQ]]->DiracDelta[x],
   Power[E,Times[Complex[0,x_?NumberQ],y__]]->DiracDelta[x y]}
```

Now apply it to the original test.

```
{Exp[-4 I], Exp[I x], Exp[2 x I], Exp[-2 x I], Exp[a x I], 
  Exp[-a x I]} /. ruleInt2
```

yields

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now a symbolic `DiracDelta` is the output for all tests with the exception of the first one. Since this is entirely numeric the computed result it output.